# Does a futex wait/wake pair achieve acquire/release semantics?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, thread-safety, futex

Given this pseudocode, where there is globally an atomic int `a` initialized to 0:

Thread 1:

```
// ... some code here (X) ...
a.store(1, relaxed);
futex_wake(&a);
```

Thread 2:

```
if (futex_wait(&a, 1) == woken_up) {
  assert(a.load(relaxed) == 1);
  // ... some code here (Y) ...
}
```

Ignoring the possibility of spurious wakeups; **can we deduce from the code above that the code `X` synchronizes-with `Y`?** Basically, it boils down to whether futex itself is meant to achieve acquire/release semantics across a wait that is woken up.

---

A bit of context: TSAN does not understand the futex system call (e.g. see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=69204), [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=69204)).

Now, normally, when using futex in order to implement a mutex, semaphore or some other synchronization primitive, one *also* has an atomic variable that gets loaded with acquire ordering by the "locking" side, and stored in release ordering by the "unlocking" side. (Above, I'm deliberately using relaxed semantics instead.)

That acquire/release is enough to achieve synchronization, be formally correct, *and* it's recognized by TSAN (which does not report anything for locks implemented this way, e.g. QBasicMutex in Qt).

This question is mostly about the suggestion offered in the forum post [linked above](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thread-sanitizer/T0G_NyyZ3s4) to mark futex operations *themselves* with acquire/release semantics. **Would such tagging be correct?**

(I know that the C++ abstract machine does not know anything about `futex`. It does not even know anything about pthreads, but TSAN does, and knows that e.g. code that happens before a `pthread_create` also happens before the code running in the newly create thread. In other words, this is not a language lawyer question...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`man futex(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html):

> **The loading of the futex word's value, the comparison of that value with the expected value, and the actual blocking will happen atomically and will be totally ordered with respect to concurrent operations performed by other threads on the same futex word.** Thus, the futex word is used to connect the synchronization in user space with the implementation of blocking by the kernel. Analogously to an atomic compare-and-exchange operation that potentially changes shared memory, blocking via a futex is an atomic compare-and-block operation.

That total ordering corresponds to C++ [`std::memory_order_seq_cst`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order):

> A load operation with this memory order performs an acquire operation, a store performs a release operation, and read-modify-write performs both an acquire operation and a release operation, **plus a single total order exists in which all threads observe all modifications in the same order**.

In other words, `futex` syscall does in the kernel the equivalent of C++11:

```
a.compare_exchange_strong(..., std::memory_order_seq_cst, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
```

Comment: I must've reread man 2 futex a dozen times and somehow never got that sentence. Thanks!

Comment: What guarantees that the futex implementation in the kernel is compatible with the implementation of `std::memory_order_seq_cst` by the particular compiler?

Comment: Although this is also what my interpretation was when I read the documentation of a futex, I'm still not entirely convinced... To get a definite answer one probably should look at the resulting kernel assembly code of a futex and compare that with the compare_exchange_strong with memory_order_seq_cst that you mention (on an ARM, for example). I wonder if this can be done on godbolt.

Comment: It says 'a single total order exists in which all threads observe all modifications in the same order <of the memory location of the futex>'. Sequential consistence would imply a single total order exists in which all threads observe all modifications to ANY atomic variable (that also uses seq-cst).

I believe that for RMW operations that total order always exists for the memory location that the RMW modifies.

Comment: @CarloWood On current x86 atomic RMW instructions do have single total order.